# How to create and recreate a index in Pymmsql in Python?

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pymssql

I'm trying to create and recreate indexes in Python but when I use this I get an error.

```
Error:
  File "src\pymssql.pyx", line 468, in pymssql.Cursor.execute
  pymssql.OperationalError: (7999, b"Could not find any index named 'Micros' for table 
  'payrolldata'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages 
  from the SQL Server\n")
```

Code:

```
with pymssql.connect ("127.0.0.1","arcdbadmin", "@rcT3chn010g13$","Micros") as myDbConn:
   with myDbConn.cursor(as_dict=True) as cursor:
       cursor.execute("""create index Micros on payrolldata(stono,payrollid,busdate) WITH(DROP_EXISTING = ON);""")
       myDbConn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use  `WITH(DROP_EXISTING = ON)` unless the index already exists.

You can [drop index if exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) first:

```
drop index if exists Micros on payrolldata
```

first if you want.  On older versions you can run

```
if exists (select * from sys.indexes where name = 'Micros' and object_id('payrolldata') = object_id)
begin
  drop index micros on payrolldata
end
```

Comment: So how can I create and drop it then recreate it every time I run this code?

Comment: DOES IF* exist in sql?

Comment: I have this error now                                                                              'cursor.execute("""DROP INDEX [IF EXISTS] Micros on payrolldata;""")
  File "src\pymssql.pyx", line 465, in pymssql.Cursor.execute
pymssql.ProgrammingError: (102, b"Incorrect syntax near 'Micros'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")'

Comment: Why do you have `IF EXISTS` in square brackets?  That's a convention from the docs indicating that it's optional.  If included it shouldn't be surrounded in `[` `]`.

Comment: File "C:\Python37-32\SqlVersionpr_import.py", line 472, in proceed
    cursor.execute("""DROP INDEX IF EXISTS Micros on payrolldata;""")
  File "src\pymssql.pyx", line 468, in pymssql.Cursor.execute
pymssql.OperationalError: (156, b"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")  Same error

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Comment: Could it be my database is name Micros?

Comment: That’s out of support.  You can query sys.indexes to see if the index exists on that version.

Comment: How would I write that?